# How to integrate wordpress blog in existing website so that blog looks part of existing website?

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress blog in my existing website. I want my wordpress blog to look similar to my website design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the theme of your wordpress blog to match your site look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can u explain how should i modify the theme

Comment: You need to modify the wordpress templates that are responsible for the look and feel. You can start here: https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/edit-wordpress-theme-html/ and here: https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/how-to-customize-a-wordpress-theme/